# Does there always exist a matrix $C$ s.t. $CA=BC$ for fixed $A, B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $A$ is an $n$ by $n$ matrix and $B$ is an $m$ by $m$ matrix. Can we always find a $m$ by $n$ matrix $C$ s.t. $CA=BC$?

Comment: About square matrice, you look for a condition called Ore condition. It is a condition for non-commutative rings to have division ring of fractions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but in general can you find a counterexample?

Comment: I have no counterexample, but, if your argument was true (at least for square matrice) then as I told, the division ring of fractions was made immediately. In my studies of this field, I don't see any such division ring

Comment: You can always take $C=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true because we can always let $\,C\,$ be a zero matrix.

But if $\,C\,$ cannot be a zero matrix, then there exists a counterexample:

Let $\,B=1\,$ be a $1\times1$ matrix, $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}\,$ be a $2\times2$ matrix and suppose $\,C=(x\ \ \ \,y)$, then we have

$$(x\ \ \ \,y)\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}=(x\ \ \ \,y)$$

which leads to

$$x+y=x$$
$$x+y=y$$

Hence $\,x=y=0\,$, which means that $\,C\,$ is a zero matrix

---

Therefore, it might be more interesting to add something like $$\det(A)\neq0,\ \ \det(B)\neq0$$

Comment: If $C$ is required to be invertible then this is precisely the condition that $A$ and $B$ are similar.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yes you are right, I did not notice that, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $C\ne0$. Consider the special case where $C$ is a column vector, $A=a$ is a scalar and $B$ is a square matrix. What does $CA=BC$ tell you about the relationship between $a$ and $B$?